# tabHost.TabWidget.SetCurrentTab(index), getContent it's possible?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-tabhost, tabwidget

When I make `tabHost.TabWidget.SetCurrentTab (index)` I do not have all the content. I have the tab that is selected but not the right content for the index.

Comment: please add some more detail so that we understand your question and can help you

Comment: I have a tableHost with TabSpec and I would like to change the current tab (the first tab) for example: I: tab1, tab2, tab3.
when i run my application, i have tab1 but i would like to have without changing the order of tab3 names with its contents.

by doing tabHost.TabWidget.SetCurrentTab (2), I have tab3 which is well selected but I do not have the contents of tab3 but tab1.
I hope it's clearer for you. thank you

Comment: have you cleared the tab selected listeners?

Comment: Mmmh no, how do you do that?